# What the last field in web server log data is about?

Tags: weblog

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
```

In web server log file, last field contains above information i.e. user agent. But here `.NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322` mentioned 2 version. From which version the web user has requested the web page? Why 2 version of .NET are mentioned here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to have more than one .NET CLR installed on a machine.
CLR + libraries and tools = .NET Framework

This UserAgent String indicates that both are installed - the request is sent by the browser that identified it self with this UA.

See for [https://www.google.com/search?q=user+agent+string+.Net+CLR](https://www.google.com/search?q=user%20agent%20string%20.Net%20CLR)

Comment: But from which .NET version the user has requested the page?

Comment: The user requested the page with a web browser. That browser send that user agent string that indicates what CLRs are installed. Why do you think that it was a .NET application that? (If a proposed answer answers the question please mark it as such (for all your questions))